# work with notification

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsnotifications

I want to postnotification when my button touchupinsideevent is done.
I want this without writing anything on button's event function

please don't give me  any reference book link i want code

brief explanation

button name: btn1

button touch up inside event:-(IBAction)btn1_click:(id)sender

one refresh event :-(void)refreshme

code that i want

**i want to call refreshme event when btn1_click event is done with out writing any thing in btn1_click event.**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                               selector:@selector(reloaddata) 
                                                   name:@"refreshtable"
                                                 object:nil];
            [btn_tagname addTarget:self action:@selector(addnew_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
    -(void)reloaddata
{
    NSLog(@"observer called");
}
    -(void)addnew_click:(id)sender
    {
    .......
    .....
    .


            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshtable" object:nil];

    }
```

now i dont want to write

**[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshtable" object:nil];**
what should i have to do.
other way is

**[self reloaddata];**
i dont want to use any of above.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have religious reasons that forbid the use of Notifications or the call to reloadData? This makes absolutely no sense

Comment: i want to learn this and improve my skill.

Answer (score 0):

Code as,

```
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshme) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

is already set

Comment: then it will probably call btn1_click, change it as refreshme

Comment: no sir i what i want i want to call refreshme method when btn1_click methods end. i am going to editmy question.

Answer (score 0):

Use uibutton function did end on exit function to call refresh me method

just connect together